# Not able to load FullCalendar premium plugin and load views in LWC Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, lwc, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to load a view from a premium plugin on a click of a button in my LWC but when I do so I get an exception "Error: The FullCalendar view "resourceTimeGridDay" does not exist. Make sure your plugins are loaded correctly.". Though I'm loading all the required plugins as well as I have set the schedulerLicenseKey.

The version used is FullCalendar Core Package v4.3.1

Source Code -->

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import fullCalendar from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullCalendar_v4_premium";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import getEventsNearbyDynamic from "@salesforce/apex/FullCalendarController.getEventsNearbyDynamic";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

//global variables
var objectName;
var startField;
var endField;
var colorField;
var additionalFilter;
var allDayField;
var titleField;

export default class FullCalendarComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    calendar;
    fullCalendarInitialized = false;

    @api titleField;
    @api objectName;
    @api startField;
    @api endField;
    @api colorField;
    @api additionalFilter;
    @api aspectRatio;
    @api allDayField;
    @api height;

    @api weekView;
    @api dayView;
    @api listView;

    @track calendarLabel;


    connectedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener('fceventclick', this.handleEventClick.bind(this));
        //this.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleScroll.bind(this));  
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.fullCalendarInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.fullCalendarInitialized = true;

        //set global vars
        objectName = this.objectName;
        startField = this.startField;
        endField = this.endField;
        colorField = this.colorField;
        additionalFilter = this.additionalFilter;
        allDayField = this.allDayField;
        titleField = this.titleField;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.js"),
            loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.css")
        ])
            .then(() => {
                //got to load core first, then plugins
                Promise.all([
                    ///packages-premium/resource-timegrid/main.min.js
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.js"),
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages-premium/resource-timegrid/main.min.js"),
                    loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.css"),
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.js"),
                    loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.css"),
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.js"),
                    loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.css"),
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/interaction/main.js"),
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment/main.js"),
                    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment-timezone/main.js"),
                ]).then(() => {
                    console.log("init");
                    this.init();
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error", error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error loading FullCalendar",
                        //message: error.message,
                        variant: "error"
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    init() {
        var calendarEl = this.template.querySelector(".calendar");
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            plugins: [
                "dayGrid",
                "timeGrid",
                "list",
                "interaction",
                "moment",
                "moment-timezone",
                "resource-common",
                "resource-daygrid",
                "resource-timegrid",
                "resource-timeline",
                "timeline",
                //'resourceTimeGrid'
            ],
            resources: [
                {
                    id: 'a',
                    title: 'Room A'
                },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    title: 'Room B'
                }
            ],
            views: {
                listDay: { buttonText: "list day" },
                listWeek: { buttonText: "list week" },
                listMonth: { buttonText: "list month" },
                timeGridWeek: { buttonText: "week time" },
                timeGridDay: { buttonText: "day time" },
                dayGridMonth: { buttonText: "month" },
                dayGridWeek: { buttonText: "week" },
                dayGridDay: { buttonText: "day" },
                resourceTimeGridDay: { buttonText: "resource view" }
            },

            eventClick: info => {
                const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('fceventclick', { detail: info });
                console.log("eventClick", info);
                this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
            },
            eventMouseEnter: info => { console.log("mouse enter", info) },
            dateClick: info => { console.log("date click", info) },
            header: false,
            /*header: {
              left: "title",
              center: "today prev,next",
              right:
                "listDay,listWeek,listMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay"
            },*/
            eventSources: [
                /*{
                  events: 'this.eventSourceHandler',
                  id: "custom"
                },*/
                {
                    events: "https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json",
                    id: "demo"
                }
            ]
        });
        this.calendar.render();
        this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
    }

    nextHandler() {
        try {
            this.calendar.next();
            this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
        } catch (exceptionVar) {
            console.log('exceptionVar--> ' + exceptionVar)
        }


    }

    previousHandler() {
        try {
            this.calendar.prev();
            this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
        } catch (exceptionVar) {
            console.log('exceptionVar--> ' + exceptionVar)
        }

    }

    dailyViewHandler() {
        try {
            this.calendar.changeView("resourceTimeGridDay");
            this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
        } catch (exceptionVar) {
            console.log('exceptionVar--> ' + exceptionVar)
        }
    }


    weeklyViewHandler() {
        try {
            this.calendar.changeView(this.weekView);
            this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
        } catch (exceptionVar) {
            console.log('exceptionVar--> ' + exceptionVar)
        }

    }

    monthlyViewHandler() {
        try {
            this.calendar.changeView('dayGridMonth');
            this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
        } catch (exceptionVar) {
            console.log('exceptionVar--> ' + exceptionVar)
        }

    }


    listViewHandler() {
        this.calendar.changeView(this.listView);
        this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
    }

    today() {
        this.calendar.today();
        this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
    }

    refresh() {
        var eventSource = this.calendar.getEventSourceById('custom');
        eventSource.refetch();
    }

    handleScroll(event) {
        console.log("handleScroll");
        event.stopImmediatePropogation();
    }


    handleEventClick(event) {
        let info = event.detail;
        console.log('Event: ' + info.event.title);
        console.log('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
        console.log('View: ' + info.view.type);
        console.log(info);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: info.event.id,
                actionName: 'view',
            },
        });
        // change the border color just for fun
        //info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';

    }

    eventSourceHandler(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        getEventsNearbyDynamic({
            startDate: info.start,
            endDate: info.end,
            objectName: objectName,
            titleField: titleField,
            startField: startField,
            endField: endField,
            colorField: colorField,
            allDayField: allDayField,
            additionalFilter: additionalFilter
        })
            .then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    let events = result;
                    let e = [];
                    for (let event in events) {
                        if (event) {
                            e.push({
                                title: events[event][titleField],
                                start: events[event][startField],
                                end: events[event][endField],
                                Id: events[event].Id,
                                id: events[event].Id,
                                color: events[event][colorField],
                                allDay: events[event][allDayField]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("num events = ", e.length);
                    successCallback(e);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("error calling apex controller:", error);
                failureCallback(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you don't seem to have loaded a script for the resource-common package, which is required to use any resource-aware or premium views. You also seem to be missing a loadScript command for the resource-daygrid and resource-timeline plugins, even though you have tried to load them into the fullcalendar.

Comment: Did not work :/

Comment: In what way, specifically? Please [edit] your post to show exactly what you did, and tell us if you get any different/new error messages etc. Otherwise it's very difficult to help you progress the issue. It's certain that you did omit those things, and they are needed for this to work, but what's not certain is if you fixed it fully/correctly, or if there's now a different issue of any sort. Remember we need to see a [mre] of the problem to be able to assist, and we cannot see your screen or read your mind. See also [ask]